# Voting for re-opening after having edited a closed question. Is that OK?

Tags: discussion, voting

The question in question: [My area of expertise at a new job is apparently being outsourced](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/93663/my-area-of-expertise-at-a-new-job-is-apparently-being-outsourced)

The comments indicate the lack of an explicit question as the closing reason. Personally, I felt there was an implicit question - but edited the question to make it explicit.

Having done that, there are now two votes to re-open, so it seems the edit has been somewhat successful - but am I 'allowed' to vote for re-opening; I have the ability - but should I exercise it?

I disagreed on the closing (despite understanding the reasoning) - but if I vote for re-opening, am I not basically assuming my edit solves the problem? Should I not leave it up to others to evaluate whether my edit is sufficient - or may I effectively vote on my own edit?

Comment: If you disagree that a question should be closed, and have enough rep to cast a reopen vote then you can cast that vote when ever you feel appropriate.  SE assumes you have enough invested in the site that you wont abuse your abilities.  In theory I think the SE powers that be can take action should they find you are using them inappropriately but if you are doing it in good faith you have no worry about that.

Comment: And in a couple of winter bash past, you'd get **A HAT** for doing that. (sorry can't find a link).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Not only are you allowed, but you are explicitly *encouraged* to cast reopen vote after improving a post.**

You can even go one step further and create a meta post to request reopen votes from other users. Include a short explanation of how your edit improves the post.

We have a [reopen-request](/questions/tagged/reopen-request) tag on meta for exactly this purpose. As a community, we should use it more often. Consider taking a look at some of the questions with that tag if you need some reference for making your own post!

Answer (score 12):

> but am I 'allowed' to vote for re-opening; I have the ability - but
>   should I exercise it?

Yes. That's basically the standard protocol.

Thanks for taking the time to attempt to improve the question.

Comment: +1 this is the best workflow, plus it puts it into the "reopen vote" review queue that way so other people can review the edited question. I just cast the 5th reopen vote myself, as Joe said thanks for taking the time!

Comment: Agreed.  By casting a reopen vote, you're saying "in its current form this question is ok".  Why does it matter if the edit was done by you or by user666 or someone else?  If you think it's ready, vote.  If you don't, don't (or vote "leave closed" if reviewing).

Comment: Diamond trifecta: fully agree as well. In fact I'd say that in most cases it doesn't make sense to spend time editing a question if it doesn't deserve to be reopened when you're done.